# No Ethereum address found to fund on Rinkeby when use Facebook post

Tags: rinkeby, faucets

[image]

I try to get some faucet from https://www.rinkeby.io/#faucet by using Facebook post and always got error "No Ethereum address found to fund".

My Facebook post is here => https://www.facebook.com/alongkorn.chetasumon/posts/4740210575995244

It should be a valid url and valid address.

Comment: take a picture of the facebook post, cause we cannot see it without having facebook account. idk if the faucet still work with facebook, i remember having problem and had to use twitter 1 year ago

Comment: i have the same issue :D

Comment: i couldnt even managed to use it via twitter, just stick to koven network. That was working fine and the process of getting eth is straightforward https://faucets.chain.link/kovan

Comment: I'm having the same issue... maybe permissions aren't public enough...? I can see it...

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2022:**

You can use others faucet to take Ether from Rinkeby Testnet into your wallet. These faucets actually work:

- https://rinkebyfaucet.com/
- https://faucets.chain.link/rinkeby